# excluding directories and it sub directories using find

Tags: unix

i have directory structure like

applicationlogic/email/FXMM

under this i have directories like, in need to exclude the funding and it's subdirectories.
when i use this command it excludes only the funding not it's subdirect

**find applicationlogic/email/FXMM -type d  ( ! -name funding )**

## directories

common/
common/scripts/
money/implementation/
money/scripts/
softmoney/implementation/
softmoney/application/
funding/limits/
funding/pilot/
funding/migration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find applicationlogic/email/FXMM -name "*funding*" -prune -o -type d -print
```

Basically, the part before `-prune` (`-name "*funding*"`)is the test for things you want to prune; the part after -o (`-type d`) is the normal test for find. and `-print` is the action.

Comment: also another question, also from this directory i need only cpp file how can do it. currently i am using find applicationlogic/email/FXMM  -name "*.cpp", how can do using the command find applicationlogic/email/FXMM -name "*funding*" -prune -o -type d -print

Comment: @Gopal Assuming you just want *.cpp files in the directories except those with "funding", then you just use `-o -name "*.cpp"` instead of `-o -type d`